# Should I use ajax in an infinite loop?

Tags: php, ajax

I need to make a site that each one of seconds shows an answer from the server.
Should I use `while (true) { }` or I should use something else?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: You can use php Cron if any server side loop action and client side "scope.setInterval” function callback in javascript.

Comment: Use `ajax` and `setInterval()`.

Comment: @RohitIUC: You can't push data from PHP to client; and you can't tell `cron` to schedule something to less than a one-minute resolution, so once-per-second cron job to get an answer from the server is not possible.

Comment: WebSockets is another way to do so. Requires modern browser though. Read [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

Comment: @Amadan Ok but I suggest "scope.setInterval" function for client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a short answer: No you shouldn't use `AJAX` in infinite or either a normal loop.

**Explanation:**

Note the 'A' in `AJAX`: It stands for `Asynchronous` wich means a task that's running in the background that may take time. So, when using `AJAX` in a loop (infinite or finite) the result may not be what you want as of loops are insanely fast and because the `Asynchronous` task that runs in that loop. Imagine you do a loop in which you do some `AJAX` that simply prints the counter of that loop, let's say from 1 to 4, the result you think you'll get is: 1, 2, 3, 4 but you'll get a result may look like this: 1, 3, 4, 2

So, to preserve the order of the desired results you can use a function, name it infiniteAJAX for example, in which you do your `AJAX` call and in the `success` handler you call infiniteAJAX.

```
function infiniteAJAX() {
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function(response) {
            // Manipulate the response
            // call infiniteAJAX()
            infiniteAJAX()
        }
    });
}
// call infiniteAJAX()
infiniteAJAX();
```

Comment: I usually do what I call is a rolling timeout.  Guess this is easier.

Comment: the same `AJAX` call may take different time to complete due to network, resources... so do the `AJAX` when the last one finishes is better than delaying it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid duplication of ajax requests (they are asynchronous, and they could take more time than an expected interval) the better way to do that is calling your request again during the callback of ajax query. For example in JQuery

```
function showMyData(){
  $.get( "app/data.html", function( data ) {
    // set your content
    $( "#container" ).html( data );
    // run again after 1 sec.
    window.setTimeout( showMyData, 1000);
  }
);
```

If you need a more accurate interval, you need to calculate the time between ajax call and response. Sometimes, it could take more than one second. 
If yopu don't do that, you probably get a lot of ajax calls waiting for response at some time.